# Transcription of plastic injection machine video

Tags: american-english

In order to improve my technical english and my mechanical knowledgments I’have been transcribing some study materials. Between 1:23 and 1:30 min of this video (https://youtu.be/qn16JtE_vLc) I could not hear the words spoken. Could anyone help me with the transcription of this snippet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not accept proofheading requests.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I heard.

> Molding cycles can last anywhere from one second for tiny parts, made in tiny molding machines, to minutes for large parts, made in presses the size of a building.

Comment: To be specific, [1:23](https://youtu.be/qn16JtE_vLc?t=83) occurs at approximately the point where the narration says "made in tiny molding machines" and the sentence finishes at [1:28](https://youtu.be/qn16JtE_vLc?t=88), but the whole sentence has been transcribed here. Likely in order to not lose its meaning.